# iOS8 Enterprise App install issue, working in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

We created ipa file by using Enterprise Apple account and placed the ipa file in server along with plist. We are able to download the app in iOS7,iOS6 devices but not able to download in iOS8 device. Below is my plist and device logs. I followed all the SO links but still not able to fix. Please help me out.

Plist:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://urlPathToIpaFile.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://urlPathToFullSizeImage.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://urlPathToDisplaySizeImage.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.techv.hrm.ios8fix</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Hrm</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
`
```

iPhone Device Logs:

```
Apr 22 22:57:47 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:57:49 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:57:49 iPhone languageassetd[125] <Notice>: (Note ) LanguageAssetLoader: download progress handler:  ASOperationCompleted
Apr 22 22:57:50 iPhone itunesstored[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.techv.hrm.ios8fix
Apr 22 22:57:50 iPhone installd[35] <Notice>: 0x381000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-4879621364680426054.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 82)
Apr 22 22:57:50 iPhone installd[35] <Notice>: 0x381000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.techv.hrm.ios8fix; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
Apr 22 22:57:50 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:57:52 iPhone installd[35] <Notice>: 0x381000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.techv.hrm.ios8fix at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/618438EA-17FF-4A14-AE57-7A01CE4516AB
Apr 22 22:57:52 iPhone installd[35] <Notice>: 0x381000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.techv.hrm.ios8fix at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB113D21-3CFA-4C90-851E-13530319C455
Apr 22 22:57:52 iPhone installd[35] <Notice>: 0x381000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.09s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 2.65s; Overall: 2.76s
Apr 22 22:57:52 iPhone itunesstored[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x17e69a60> com.techv.hrm.ios8fix (Placeholder) withPhase:3
Apr 22 22:57:52 iPhone itunesstored[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.techv.hrm.ios8fix.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x17e55cf0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Apr 22 22:57:53 iPhone lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
Apr 22 22:57:53 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
Apr 22 22:57:53 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
Apr 22 22:57:53 iPhone lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
Apr 22 22:57:54 iPhone filecoordinationd[141] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.techv.hrm.ios8fix (bundle id (null), BC14F04B-E2D6-45A4-BAC1-AC48826EC2EA)
Apr 22 22:57:54 iPhone filecoordinationd[141] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.techv.hrm.ios8fix (bundle id com.apple.iaptransportd, E2E1F85F-19B5-4AAB-AACB-95487D662BDB)
Apr 22 22:57:55 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:58:05 iPhone syncdefaultsd[182] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "ignored" on (null)
Apr 22 22:58:06 iPhone softwareupdated[40] <Notice>: 00319000 : Unexpected XPC error on peer connection: Connection invalid
Apr 22 22:58:07 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:58:15 iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[161] <Notice>: URL retrieved https://cl1.apple.com/1/v3/lasdgsm.db.gz, size: 4551881 
Apr 22 22:58:15 iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[161] <Notice>: uncompressing to /var/mobile/Library/LASD/lasdgsm.db.tmp
Apr 22 22:58:17 iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[161] <Notice>: Moving /var/mobile/Library/LASD/lasdgsm.db.tmp to /var/mobile/Library/LASD/lasdgsm.db
Apr 22 22:58:17 iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[161] <Notice>: Downloaded gsm database version 0.2015.03.15 successfully
Apr 22 22:58:17 iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[161] <Notice>: Fetching URL https://cl1.apple.com/1/v3/lasdumts.db.gz
Apr 22 22:58:24 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:58:30 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:58:41 iPhone backboardd[57] <Notice>: ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=0.0500
Apr 22 22:58:42 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 22 22:58:44 iPhone backboardd[57] <Notice>: ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=1.0000
Apr 22 22:58:54 iPhone nsurlsessiond[113] <Warning>: tcp_connection_set_timeframe Using minimum duration of 1 minute.
```